# WinJS Listview shows undefined when navigating quickly

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I have a WinJS application with listviews in which if quickly navigate between pages before the listview is fully loaded, the next page shows the listview with all elements in it bound as "undefined".

So say I have a hub page with a "to do" that is filtered to only show 6 items, and there is a header that navigates to the full "to do" page, when the hub page is displayed but before it is fully loaded I click on the header link to the "to do" page, the app then goes to the "to do" page, but the items show up with all the properties in the tile as "undefined".

I am using IndexedDB as my data store.

My home page code looks like this:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        WinJS.Utilities.query("a").listen("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate(e.currentTarget.href);
        }, false); 

        viewModel = new HomeViewModel(element);
        viewModel.load(); //loads from indexed db

    },
    //etc...
```

To Do Page:

```
 WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/ToDo/ToDo.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {    
            viewModel = new ToDoViewModel(element);

            viewModel.load();
        },
etc//
```

I know there isn't much to go off, but any ideas would be appreciated.

Also tips on how to debug something like this would be great.

### Update

I narrowed it down to this one line from the Hub Page:

```
myLib.GetData(todaysDate, function (result) {
  that.trendsModel.today = result;
  WinJS.Binding.processAll(that.el.querySelector("#dataPanel"), that.trendsModel); //<--Right Here
});
```

If I remove that, then when I load the second page the data doesn't show as undefined. What is interesting is the data initially shows correctly on the second page and then it changes to "undefined".

### Solution

My fix:

```
myLib.GetData(todaysDate, function (result) {
  var element = that.el.querySelector("#dataPanel");

  that.trendsModel.today = result;

  if(element) {
    WinJS.Binding.processAll(element, that.trendsModel); 
  }
});
```

At the point when when the callback returns, I am already on the second page. So the selector was not found returning null. If you pass null to processAll it tries to bind the whole page which is why I was able to see the correct data for a second then it changes to undefined...Wow, what a doozy. I guess it makes sense but what a pain to find.

Hope it helps someone in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myLib.GetData(todaysDate, function (result) {
  var element = that.el.querySelector("#dataPanel");

  that.trendsModel.today = result;

  if(element) {
    WinJS.Binding.processAll(element, that.trendsModel); 
  }
});
```

At the point when when the callback returns, I am already on the second page. So the selector was not found returning null. If you pass null to processAll it tries to bind the whole page which is why I was able to see the correct data for a second then it change to undefined...Wow, what doozy. I guess it makes sense but what a pain to find.

Answer (score 1):

Your ToDoViewModel, and HomeViewModel need to be *observable*. This means they need to mix in from `WinJS.Binding.mixin`, and for the properties that you pull in asynchronously, they need to call `this.notify("propertyName", newVal, oldVal)` from the property setter.

Note that you need to have getter/setter properties. e.g.

```
var bindingBase = WinJS.Class.mix(function() {}, WinJS.Binding.mixin);
WinJS.Namespace.define("YourNamespace", {
    ToDoViewModel: WinJS.Class.derive(bindingBase, function constructor() {
    }, {
        _titleStorage: "",
        title: {
            get: function() { return this._titleStorage; },
            set: function(newValue) {
                if(newValue === this._titleStorage) {
                    return;
                }

                var old = this._titleStorage;
                this._titleStorage = newValue;
                this.notify("title", newValue, old);
             }
        }
    }),
});
```

Comment: I don't follow, why do they need to be observable? The data is not being changed. The items bind correctly, the issue only comes up when I jump between screens without letting the data fully load. Thanks!

Comment: This is because the indexeddb calls are async -- theres no synchronous API in WWA  -- so they aren't complete when these controls are created. Since IndexedDB doesn't complete the transaction until control yields to the browser, you aren't getting values *after* the listview has rendered it.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will experiment a little tonight. What I am binding is an array in the view model which is loaded from indexed db, and is not very apparent based on the code I shared. I do have a callback to tell me when the array is loaded from indexed db (I am using async). I am aware of promises, guessing I need to chain the indexed db data first and then let the binding happen.

Comment: If you wanna share a bit more of your code, we can dig a little more. There are some subtleties in IndexedDB. I have a WinJS-promise compatible wrapper at https://github.com/grork/db.js

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I looked at your fork of the library along with Aaron Powell's. I wanted the raw indexed db experience first before using a lib :) Will play around little bit and come back w/ results. Thanks!

Comment: I started on the raw approach, and it became a callback nightmare. I think I gained the experience you want from porting it, so I ended up being OK thanks to that porting experience :)

Comment: I finally narrowed it down to this line
inside the callback of an async operation, I will update my question:
WinJS.Binding.processAll(that.el.querySelector("#trendsToday"), that.trendsModel);